# Putting a mobile phone in airplane mode

Tags: vocabulary, contemporary-latin, modern-life, technology

Having flown quite a bit over the last few months, the vocabulary is fresh in my mind — but only in English.
**How can I say "my mobile phone is in airplane mode" in Latin?**

There are a couple of issues with translating this:

- What is a mobile phone? I prefer *telephonulum*, but *telephonum mobile* makes sense too. This puzzles me far less than the next two points.
- Is there a good adjective to translate "airplane"? Perhaps *aeroplanarius*? There might be other reasonable derivatives and stems one could use.
- What is a good word for "mode"? Despite the obvious etymological connection, *modus* does not look like a good translation to me. The best word I could think of is *status*. Is this a good translation, or should I use something else?

My attempt is this: *Telephonulum meum in statu aeroplanario est.*
How would you go about translating this, and why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is old, and I think that nobody has answered it until now because there are no strong opinions about it. *Telephonulum* and *status* are good choices. My only objection is *aeroplanarius.*

I am not an expert, but as far as I can gather from *Vicipaedia,* Ebbe Vilborg and David Morgan, the best proposers of Latin terms for modern stuff, were careful in distinguishing Greek words like *aeroplanum,* where they kept the connecting *-o-,* from purely Latin words, *aeriportus* and *aerinavis,* where they preferred the connecting *-i-* required by *apophonia Latina.* Following the same line of thought, I’d rather use a Greek suffix for a Greek word, and say *status aeroplanicus* instead of *aeroplanarius.* (Symmetrically, I’d say *aerinavalis.*) [*Αεροπλανικός*](http://greek_greek.enacademic.com/9024/%CE%B1%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%BB%CE%B1%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C%CF%82) exists in Modern Greek. However, it is not used in this context, because the set phrase is *λειτουργία πτήσης* “flight mode”. I will definitely **not** propose *status volitatorius.*

Romance languages have no such adjectives: they use a simple noun after “mode”: *modo avión* (Sp.), *mode avion* (Fr.), *modo aereo* (It.)... and cannot be used as examples.

Comment: Also _modo avión_ (m., airplane, also a noun) in Spanish

Comment: Hmm, I can see the argument for using -i- instead of -o- for compounds where both parts are from Latin, but even though "planus/-um/-a" is Latin, isn't the word "aer" originally a loanword from Greek?

Comment: @Rafael thank you very much. Answer corrected.